# How to ng-repeat even or odd items?

Tags: angularjs, css

I'd like to break my unordered list into even and odd loops with each column beginning with 1, 2, 3 and 4 using ng-repeat. What's a good way to do this? I don't think ng-class-even or ng-class-odd is good enough for what I want to accomplish, but it may play a part.

I've an idea of how to manipulate css3 columns using AngularJS by looping even and odd numbers to get this:

1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12

Comment: unordered in terms of what? and what do you mean by "even and odd" while saying that you want "1, 2, 3, 4"?

Comment: @Dylan Yes I wrote an answer already but your question needs to be more specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Make use of [`ngClassOdd`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassOdd) and [`ngClassEven`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassEven)  directives**

```
<ol ng-init="names=['John', 'Mary', 'Cate', 'Suz']">
  <li ng-repeat="name in names">
   <span ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
     {{name}}
   </span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

with `css`

```
.odd {
  color: red;
}
.even {
  color: blue;
}
```

will give you this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$index % 4` on ng-class

Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3pgKUYH7s8NhCXatghw9?p=preview)

Comment: This link to Plunker doesn't provide example of `$index % 4` use.

Comment: That's odd, I could swear it was the link.  I updated - http://plnkr.co/edit/3pgKUYH7s8NhCXatghw9?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
<li ng-repeat="person in people" ng-class="{even: !$even, odd: !$odd}">
{{person.name}} lives in {{person.city}}
</li>


$scope.people = [
{name: "Ari", city: "San Francisco"},
{name: "Erik", city: "Seattle"}
];
```